# Is there any way to maintain a parent-child relationship with json files using angularjs

Tags: java, html, angularjs, json

I have two traslation json files with name "translation_en.json" and  "translation_en_us.json". Lets assume that i  have 300 keys in first one and i want to override all theses keys into second by making parent child relation.

EX :

### translation_en.json

"one" : "One",
"two" : "Two"

### translation_en_us.json

"three" : "Three"
"four" : "Four"

So if i call second json file then i should get first file's data also.

Comment: Look at angular.extend

Comment: Thanks , but can we do with file ? Because i saw this example only with object as argument.

Comment: Once you receive the file, you have the object, which you can then extend with the object you receive from the other file. Or do it server side...but I'm not a JAva person so I can't answer that.